# How to switch to the next thread in VS2010

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging

When I step over (F10) in the debugger, I am staying on the thread I am currently in.

Therefore, when I step over a line of code, and the process crash in an over thread, I am not able to see in which thread it went.

As I don't know in which thread the crash is happening, I can not simply click on it in the thread window.

Do you know how to switch to "guilty" thread ?

Thanks

Comment: Debugging threads can be a PITA some times, so I'll just through a few questions out that come off the top of my head. What happens when you Step Into (F11) rather than Step Over? Does a try/catch block around the code catch an exception and provide you a stack trace? Do you have the code of the other threads, so you can place a few breakpoints around and step through a few of the threads?

Comment: When you step, the debugger essentially sets a breakpoint on the next line, and then lets all threads run until something interesting happens (like some thread getting to that breakpoint, or a crash).  So it's not that you're actually "staying on the thread".  When there's a crash, the debugger will show the call stack of the thread that crashed (the guilty thread).

Comment: @Gary I can not put a try catch block since i do not know which line neither which thread is crashing.

Comment: @Adrian Unfortunately, the call stack is just a stack of .dll, or maybe I am doing something wrong. I can not see in the stack which line of my code are calling those dll

Comment: If you app crashed inside the debugger, it automatically goes to the "crash-thread"...

Comment: But I think I do not have access to the source code of that thread, so I would like to know which is the part of my code calling that thread

Comment: You should know what YOU'RE calling though in your code that's referencing an outside library and loading another thread and causing the thread to crash, correct? Post some code on where it's breaking in YOUR code and we can likely figure out what you're sending to that thread that's causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into Debug >> Windows >> threads to see all your threads. You can also right lick on thread and select 'switch thread'.

Comment: Yes but I don't know to which thread to switch as I don't know which one is crashing

Comment: From that I remember I fixed a similar bug a while ago, it was on eclipse ide but maybe you can draw clues from it. I had to look at the values in registers when the crash occurred. I think I was tracking its values before the crash. Maybe you step into the assembly code and debug instruction by instruction.